# Power/Reset button not working after failing a CPU stress test

Tags: display, cpu, power, overclocking, reset

I overclocked my cpu and was stress testing it using a software. Then suddenly my monitor lost its signal. I thought this was another symptom of overclock failure and tried to hit Power/ Reset button. But non of the buttons worked. Case fans were still spinning at low speed and motherboard led still on. I had to unplug the power cord to restart my computer.

My questions:

1. How can a monitor & Power/ Reset button stop 
       functioning when stress testing a cpu?
2. Does it indicate that I damaged my PC components 
       (MOBO, PSU, etc)?

The Build:

```
Ryzen 1950x with Enermax TR4 360 AIO

Gskill 3600mhz DDR4 RAM

Asus Zenith Extreme MOBO

MSI GTX GAMING X 1080TI

Corsair HX1000i PSU
```

The Testing Software:

```
Linx 0.8 AMD edition
```

Comment: Most likely, the monitor is irrelevant. Its the GPU or onboard video that stopped working. You did not mention, after unplugging the computer, you say you restarted the computer. Is it working?

Comment: It does work fine after restarting it. But whenever I run the stress testing program, the symptom repeats.

Comment: Your symptoms are a signed of an unstable overclock.